I am trying to show that a certain parameter-dependant function is continuous on R+
the function is $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x f(t)} dt, \quad (x, t) \in \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}$ and $f(t)=e^{it}-1-it $
first i proved that:

$|e^{xf(t)}|= e^{-2xsin(\frac{t}{2})^2}$
$|e^{xf(t)}|\leq e^{(\frac{-2xt²}{\pi^2})},\quad t\in[-\pi, \pi]$

i want to show that $\Phi(x)$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}^+$

let $\epsilon>0, a\in\mathbb{R}^+: |x-a|<\epsilon$
I showed that $|\Phi(x)-\Phi(a)|\leq4\pi e^{-2x}\epsilon$, using the two properties listed above, and the power series expansion of $|1-e^{2\epsilon}| \sim 2\epsilon$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow0$.
this means that as $\epsilon \rightarrow0,$. $|\Phi(x)-\Phi(a)|\leq4\pi e^{-2x}\epsilon \rightarrow0$
so $Φ(x)\rightarrowΦ(a)$ as $x\rightarrow a$, $\forall a>0$ hence the continuity over $\mathbb{R}^+$


the proof i was presented shows $\Phi$ is continuous because

$h(t)=e^{x f(t)}$ is continuous $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}^+$
$h(x)=e^{x f(t)}$ is continuous $\forall t \in [-\pi, \pi]$
$e^{x f(t)}$ is bounded by a riemann integrable function


Please check the definition of $\Phi.$ You may have written $x$ under the integral sign where you mean $t.$ Also, $t$ is real.

you are correct i fixed it, t is real, f(t) maps into C. but the integral is written right

When trying to prove convergence of integrals, the first instruments at hand are dominated convergence (Lebesgue) and monotone convergence (Beppo Levi).
Consider the limit of $\Phi(x)$ as $x\to x_0\in\mathbb R^+.$ The integrand converges to $e^{{x_0}f(t)}$ pointwise for each $t$ separately (first bullet point) and is absolutely bounded, as a function of $t,$ by the constant 1 (third bullet point), which is an integrable function on the interval $[-\pi,+\pi].$ Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem then guarantees that the integrand, as a function of $t,$ converges to its limit also in the norm of $L^1([-\pi,+\pi]);$ in particular, the integrals converge to the integral of the pointwise limit, i.e., to $\Phi(x_0).$
